# Internet Explorer 11 | Angular 4 - CORS request fails (XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.)

Tags: angular, cors, internet-explorer-11, angular2-services, preflight

I am working on an Angular 4 application where I make REST calls to API hosted on another domain.
e.g.
I am working on http://mycompanydomain.com/ and call REST services on http://othercompanydomain.com.

Everything works fine on various browsers. However, on Internet explorer (11), I get the following error(s)/warnings:

```
XMLHttpRequest for https://esb-dev.tibco.com:8446/services/v1/authorize required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

XMLHttpRequest for https://esb-dev.tibco.com:8446/services/v1/authorize required CORS preflight.

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

Would appreciate any inputs here.

Answer (score 0):

IE will not treat the request as cross-origin and will see no need to add the Origin: header

Comment: Why do you think this is happening? And how to solve it?

Comment: I think this issue may be relevant of CORS.
To enable cross-origin requests in IE and need to install cors extension in IE,  hope it will work